# why website doesnt' display special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

here is my problem, i got a website that displays the reviews from customers from my database (clearDB) in the table 'avis' but when i open my heroku-app all the letters with accent are changed by '?'...
[image]
It seems that the problem comes from the database because my html pages display well the letters with accent.
So i checked ma table 'avis' and encode is utf8_general_ci, here's a pic
[image]
And here is my index.php code that gets the queries to database:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
...
</head>
...
<?php
              // Connexion à la base de données
              $servername = "............";
              $username = "............";
              $password = "............";
              $dbname = "................";

              try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                // Récupérer les avis approuvés de la table "avis"
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM avis WHERE approuve = :approuve");
                $approuve = 1; // Seuls les avis approuvés
                $stmt->bindParam(':approuve', $approuve);
                $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $nom = $row['nom'];
                    $commentaire = $row['commentaire'];
                    $note = $row['note'];

                    // Afficher les informations de l'avis
                    echo "<div class='avis mx-5 my-3'>";

                    // Générer les étoiles en fonction de la note
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $note; $i++) {
                      echo "★";
                    }

                    echo "</p>";
                    echo "<p><i>$commentaire</i></p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                  }
                } else {
                  echo "Aucun avis approuvé pour le moment.";
                }

                // Fermer la connexion à la base de données
                $conn = null;
              } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Échec de la connexion à la base de données : " . $e->getMessage();
              }
              ?>
```

If someone could help me solve this problem...
I just started deploy my website on heroku yesterday and database on clearDB!
On localhost using phpmyadmin that was good.

In phpmyadmin i exported my database and imported in heroku database (clearDB) with MySQL Workbench, then i changed the connections to server in all my php pages.

Thanx for helping me!

Comment: [utf8 all the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) all sides need the same character set collation, i believe there must be a lot of threads for that